# PHP 5.4.21 on IIS 7 dropping “<” and “</” in tags

Tags: php, xml, iis, iis-7

I am generating XML data using a PHP script on an IIS 7 server with PHP 5.4.21. I noticed the data was not passing XML validation because seemingly random tags would have their "<" or "</" stripped from them. I ran some tests to see what the problem is by putting the expected XML output in a 2 separate files, one with a .php extension (with no actual PHP in it) and one with a .xml extension (exact same content of the .php file but this will not have to pass through the PHP interpreter). The .xml extension file did not have any characters disappear while the .php extension file did. Then running the same PHP script on my local WAMP server worked fine as well. This all leads me to assume that the issue must be with PHP. The problem is I have no clue why it is happening and I have so far been unsuccessful in searching Google for an answer.

Here is a code sample that causes the bug so you can get a bette idea of what is happening.

```
<?php
    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
    print "<appguide>\n";
    print "\t<wheels>\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < 80; $i++) {
        print "\t\t<wheel>\n";
        print "\t\t\t<someone>{$i}</someone>\n";
        print "\t\t\t<set>{$i}</set>\n";
        print "\t\t\t<us>{$i}</us>\n";
        print "\t\t\t<up>{$i}</up>\n";
        print "\t\t\t<the>{$i}</the>\n";
        print "\t\t\t<bomb>{$i}</bomb>\n";
        print "\t\t</wheel>\n";
    }

    print "\t</wheels>\n";
    print "</appguide>\n";
?>
```

This should simply print the same data 80 times within the "<wheels>" section. But viewing the source of it on the IIS7/PHP5.4.2 machine comes up with this:

```
<wheel>
    <someone>30</someone>
    <set>30set>
    <us>30</us>
    <up>30</up>
    <the>30</the>
    <bomb>30</bomb>
</wheel>
```

As you can see the "</" is missing from the "</set>" in the 31st iteration in the loop. Even if I do not use PHP to generate the XML data and have the expected output pasted in the file (same as you would an XML file), it will still have missing brackets.

So does anyone have any clue what could be causing this?!

*Update for the person that asked about the HTTP response headers:*

**Live Server**

```
Content-Length:10326
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 18 Mar 2014 22:35:47 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.21
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

**Local Server**

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Tue, 18 Mar 2014 22:35:19 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.1
```

Comment: Weird. It's working fine for me with your code. (PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.2)

Comment: Yes. Like I said in the original post, "running the same PHP script on my local WAMP server worked fine". Hence why I posted the IIS and PHP versions (which neither match your test).

Comment: Are the HTTP response headers the same in both servers?

Comment: Are you sure you have no space after your php closing tag? Or maybe in any included file in the actual one?

Comment: There is nothing after my closing PHP tag, although I am unsure why that would cause this. As for the HTTP response headers, I updated the original post with them.

Comment: Probably wont help, but shouldn't the content-type be `text/xml`?

Comment: The actual script has the `header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");` but I trimmed the code down to the most minimal example that still causes the issue for the sake of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the weirdest bugs are encoding-related. There may be something special secret meaning for the IIS7 in this unique

```
t>30</s
```

combination - it only occurs once through your loop, at the 31 iteration.

I have no access to an IIS but as a test I'd try to temporarily rename the

```
<set>
```

tag and see if anything changes.

Comment: I had thought about that as well. You can change the tag to say anything, but if the # of chars is the same, the error will be in the exact same location.

Comment: Sorry this should have been a comment and not an answer, too late to change. 2 more things that come to mind: 1) did you try using _echo_ instead of _print_ -- or _heredoc_? and 2) are the php.ini setting on the working machine and the non-working one are identical?